# Cleaner way to plot multiple bar charts of different outcome variables (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wondering if there is a better way to produce 4 barcharts of different outcome variables arranged in a grid:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
library(cowplot)

bar1 <- ggplot(data = subset(data, !is.na(MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile))) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile))
bar2 <- ggplot(data = subset(data, !is.na(AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile))) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile))
bar3 <- ggplot(data = subset(data, !is.na(MHQ_Heading_Female_Quartile))) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = MHQ_Heading_Female_Quartile))
bar4 <- ggplot(data = subset(data, !is.na(AHQ_Heading_Female_Quartile))) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = AHQ_Heading_Female_Quartile))

plot_grid(bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, ncol = 2)
```

However, there is a lot of repeated code- is there some function or way to create the same plot with ggplot2 in fewer lines?

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(data, 20))` **in the question** please?

Comment: ^ Just added it thanks!

Comment: put your data in a long format and facet by the variable/columns which contains the information of the x axis

Comment: also, please have a read how to create a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve your data frame contains way too much information which is all not necessary for the question

Comment: Do you really need to give all 43 (!) columns of your data to make your question reproducible?

Comment: ^ Yes you are absolutely right. I have never used the dput function before (I'm very new to R). In hindsight, I would've subsetted the dataframe first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert relevant columns from wide to long (the ones ending in `"_Quartile"`) and then use `facet_wrap` to show the 4 plots in a 2x2 grid with `scales = "free"`.

Something like this:

```
data %>%
    gather(key, value, ends_with("Quartile")) %>%
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(value)) +
    geom_bar() +
    facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free", ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you need to make it a long format using `dplyr` gather (or reshape package) and then facet over this.

```
`data %>%
  select( MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile, AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile, MHQ_Heading_Female_Quartile, AHQ_Heading_Female_Quartile) %>%
  gather("Type", "Range", MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile:AHQ_Heading_Female_Quartile) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Range)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Range)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~Type, scales="free")`
```

I'll leave it to you to clean the graphs up but that's the basic premise.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the column names to be shown into `nms` and then for each one use `qplot` to create a `ggplot` object so that `bars` is a list of such objects.  Then run `plot_grid` on that.

```
nms <- grep("Quartile", names(data), value = TRUE)
bars <- lapply(nms, function(nm) qplot(na.omit(data[[nm]]), xlab = nm))
do.call("plot_grid", bars)
```

[image: screenshot]